# Could not decode `RuntimeCall::System.0`

Tags: subxt

Can somebody explain what this means?

```
 Rpc(ClientError(Call(Custom(ErrorObject { code: ServerError(1002), message: "Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Could not decode `RuntimeCall::System.0`:\n\tCould not decode `Call`, variant doesn't exist\n", data: Some(RawValue("RuntimeApi(\"Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Bad input data provided to validate_transaction: Could not decode `RuntimeCall::System.0`:\\n\\tCould not decode `Call`, variant doesn't exist\\n\")")) }))))',
```

I have `pallet-balance` in my runtime, and I'm using subxt to perform a transfer:

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "../artifacts/my_metadata.scale")]
pub mod metadata{}

#[derive(Encode, Decode, Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct ChargeAssetTxPayment {
    pub tip: u128,
    pub asset_id:Option<u8>
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let api = subxt::OnlineClient::<MyConfig>::new().await.expect("should work");

    let dest = subxt::ext::sp_runtime::MultiAddress::Id(sp_keyring::AccountKeyring::Bob.into());

  
    let balance_transfer_tx = metadata::tx().balances().transfer(
        dest,
        10_000,
    );

    let alice_pair = SR25519Pair::from_string("//Alice", None).unwrap();
    
    let charge = ChargeAssetTxPayment { tip: 10, asset_id: Some(0) };
    let extra_params = (
        api.genesis_hash(),
        Era::Immortal,
        charge
        );

   let events = api.tx()
        .sign_and_submit_then_watch(&balance_transfer_tx, &alice_pair, extra_params)
        .await.expect("should work!")
        .wait_for_finalized_success()
        .await.expect("should work!!!");
}
```

The error happens at `sign_and_submit_then_watch()`
I do not quite understand the issue of `RuntimeCall::System.0`.
I printed the `validation_details()` of `balance_transfer_tx` and it returned fine.
Where am I doing wrong?

Also, [see this comment](https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client/issues/626#issuecomment-1647834800), because it's the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely culprit is that your `MyConfig` type is configured incorrectly (most likely that the `ExtrinsicParams` you are using do not line up with the chain in question). The docs were recently extended to provide much more info on how to construct the config, so perhaps this is helpful:

https://docs.rs/subxt/0.30.1/subxt/book/setup/config/index.html

Otherwise, note that we are going to improve this config (most notably the ExtrinsicParams) to make the much more robust and simpler to set up (follow this issue to keep up with this: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/1062)